# sequence/stack diagam for recursive function

Tags: python, string, recursion, sequence-diagram

for the code below:

```
def printList(L):

   if L:

       print L[0]

       printList(L[1:])
```

I can have sequence diagram like this:

```
# NON PYTHON PSEUDO CODE

PrintList([1,2,3])

  prints [1,2,3][0] => 1

  runs printList([1,2,3][1:]) => printList([2,3])

  => we're now in printList([2,3])

        prints [2,3][0] => 2

        runs printList([2,3][1:]) => printList([3])

    => we are now in printList([3])

          prints [3][0] => 3

          runs printList([3][1:]) => printList([])

          => we are now in printList([])

                "if L" is false for an empty list, so we return None

    => we are back in printList([3])

          it reaches the end of the function and returns None

  => we are back in printList([2,3])

    it reaches the end of the function and returns None

=> we are back in printList([1,2,3])

  it reaches the end of the function and returns None
```

**So my question is if I change the code to:**

```
def printList(L):

   if L:
       print L[0]
       printList(L[1:])
       print L[0]
```

**How would the sequence diagram change, I want to understand what exactly happens during the execution of this code.**

Comment: Do you understand the sequence diagram you posted? Have you **tried** to diagram the new code?

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel: yes I understand my diagram, but I don't know if python execute all printList(L[1:]) first and the the last print L[0] or do it after every printList(L[1:])....

Comment: Are you sure you understand that diagram? I sure don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statement called after the recursive calls will all get hit "on the way back up". That is, each of your statements: "it reaches the end of the function and returns None" can be changed to "it prints the current value of L[0], reaches the end of the function, and returns None", which will be 3, 2, and 1 respectively.

Like so:

```
PrintList([1,2,3])
prints [1,2,3][0] => 1
runs printList([1,2,3][1:]) => printList([2,3])
=> we're now in printList([2,3])
    prints [2,3][0] => 2
    runs printList([2,3][1:]) => printList([3])
    => we are now in printList([3])
        prints [3][0] => 3
        runs printList([3][1:]) => printList([])
        => we are now in printList([])
            "if L" is false for an empty list, so we return None
        => we are back in printList([3])
        prints [3][0] => 3
        it reaches the end of the function and returns None
    => we are back in printList([2,3])
   prints [2,3][0] => 2
   it reaches the end of the function and returns None
=> we are back in printList([1,2,3])
prints [1,2,3][0] => 1
it reaches the end of the function and returns None
```